# Переопределяются ли аннотации в предках классов?

Tags: java, аннотации

Добрый день.

Если используем аннотации, к примеру, для класса.
У нас есть некий абстрактный класс `А`. У него есть предок, класс `B`. 
И там и там есть аннотация `@MyAnnotation`. В аннотации есть поле

```
String[] value() default {};
```

В итоге получили примерно такое:

```
@MyAnnotation({"str1","str2"})
abstract class A {}

@MyAnnotation({"str3","str4"})
class B extends A {}
```

Вопрос: Будут ли суммироваться все значения из класса и суперкласса, или просто возьмется значение из текущего объекта `B`. Либо, может, еще какие хитрости есть в аннотациях?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наследование аннотаций возможно при использовании аннотации [`@Inherited`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html). В вашем случае произойдет просто перекрытие.

**Аннотации**

```
@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InheritedAnnotation {
    String name();
}

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UninheritedAnnotation {
    String name();
}
```

**Тестовые классы**

```
@InheritedAnnotation(name = "A1")
public class A1 {}

@InheritedAnnotation(name = "B1")
public class B1 extends A1 {}

public class C1 extends A1 {}

@UninheritedAnnotation(name = "A2")
public class A2 {}

@UninheritedAnnotation(name = "B2")
public class B2 extends A2 {}

public class C2 extends A2 {}
```

**Тест**

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new A1().getClass().getAnnotation(InheritedAnnotation.class));
    System.out.println(new B1().getClass().getAnnotation(InheritedAnnotation.class));
    System.out.println(new C1().getClass().getAnnotation(InheritedAnnotation.class));
    System.out.println(new A2().getClass().getAnnotation(UninheritedAnnotation.class));
    System.out.println(new B2().getClass().getAnnotation(UninheritedAnnotation.class));
    System.out.println(new C2().getClass().getAnnotation(UninheritedAnnotation.class));
}
```

**Вывод**

```
//@org.example.InheritedAnnotation(name=A1)
//@org.example.InheritedAnnotation(name=B1)
//@org.example.InheritedAnnotation(name=A1)
//@org.example.UninheritedAnnotation(name=A2)
//@org.example.UninheritedAnnotation(name=B2)
//null
```

Comment: Стоит отметить, что даже @Inherited не позволяет наследовать аннотации от интерфейсов.